# Как скачать view-source любой веб-страницы на python?

Tags: python, парсер

Как скачать view-source любой веб-страницы?

---

Пример:
У нас есть url: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/
Мне нужно скачать view-source:бhttps://ru.stackoverflow.com/

Comment: Стандартный запрос и так возвращает код страницы... Например, `requests.get(url).text`.

Comment: @nomnoms12 а почему например для https://vk.com/durov я получаю не то что в view-source? Только что прочитал про selenium с ним попробую как нибудь.

Comment: @Swan потому что сайт может отдавать разным клиентам разный код, если захочет

Comment: @Swan у ВК много версий (мобильная, например). При ответе сервер ориентируется на заголовок `User-Agent`. К тому же Вам вернутся не все данные сразу, потому что некоторые подгружаются с помощью `JS` уже после загрузки страницы.